# Android MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Если наследовать класс `MediaPlayer` и создать в нем, например, переменную в начале кода:

```
 public class Music extends MediaPlayer{
    String url = null;
```

то после очистки ресурсов при вызове `release()`, переменная url сохранит свое значение?

Если нет, то каким способом ее сохранять после `release()` внутри этого класса?

Comment: должна сохраняться, но не внутри класса, а как поле объекта.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В общем этот вопрос не о плеере, а о наследовании. Если наследник объявляет свою переменную и хочет очистить ее при вызове метода, объявленного в родителе, он должен перегрузить этот метод, добавив свою функциональность.

В данном слечае

```
public class Music extends MediaPlayer{
    String url = null;
    // some code
    @Override
    public void release() {
         super.release(); // call method of super classs
         // now perform your cleanup
         url = null;
    }
}
```